# avconv outputs every video in landscape rotation, regardless of metadata or transpose

Tags: ubuntu, video, avconv

I am trying to convert .mov files to .mp4 so they can be played on any device. I am using ubuntu 14.04 with avconv v0.20-6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (built on Dec 7 2016 with gcc 4,8).

If I try just:

```
avconv -i input.mov output.mp4
```

It converts to mp4 fine, but if the video was portrait it is automatically rotated to landscape. If the video was landscape it is not rotated. I also tried with mp4 videos taken with my android device and the same thing happens. This is the original metadata for a MOV file (command to get the metadata is first line):

```
avconv -i IMG_0022.MOV
avconv version 9.20-6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Dec  7 2016 21:22:31 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1d5e240] Could not find codec parameters (Data: mebx / 0x7862656D, 0 kb/s)
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_0022.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
  Duration: 00:00:03.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10705 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720, 10823 kb/s, 24.01 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 61 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
    Stream #0.2(und): Data: mebx / 0x7862656D, 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
    Stream #0.3(und): Data: mebx / 0x7862656D, 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
At least one output file must be specified
```

When I ran

```
avconv -i IMG_0022.mov -strict -2 out.mp4
```

this is what I got:

```
avconv -i IMG_0022.MOV -strict -2 out.mp4
avconv version 9.20-6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Dec  7 2016 21:22:31 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1fdab00] Could not find codec parameters (Data: mebx / 0x7862656D, 0 kb/s)
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_0022.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
  Duration: 00:00:03.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10705 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720, 10823 kb/s, 24.01 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 61 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
    Stream #0.2(und): Data: mebx / 0x7862656D, 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
    Stream #0.3(und): Data: mebx / 0x7862656D, 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.25 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 22500 tbn, 24.01 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 200 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-25 22:58:59
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> aac)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=   75 fps= 29 q=32765.0 Lsize=    1673kB time=3.04 bitrate=4507.2kbits/s
video:595kB audio:74kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 149.985988%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] frame I:1     Avg QP:27.41  size: 47219
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] frame P:43    Avg QP:25.60  size: 28610
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] frame B:31    Avg QP:27.26  size: 11417
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] consecutive B-frames: 21.3% 66.7% 12.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] mb I  I16..4:  1.5% 76.0% 22.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] mb P  I16..4:  2.5% 13.7%  5.9%  P16..4: 50.4% 15.5%  7.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 4.4%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] mb B  I16..4:  0.5%  2.1%  1.0%  B16..8: 52.8%  4.8%  0.8%  direct: 6.6%  skip:31.4%  L0:44.6% L1:51.8% BI: 3.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] 8x8 transform intra:62.9% inter:58.8%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 79.0% 89.8% 36.9% inter: 33.5% 55.1% 1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] i16 v,h,dc,p:  7% 11% 32% 50%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  8%  9% 17%  3% 20% 25% 10%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 12% 12% 22%  4% 18% 19%  6%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] i8c dc,h,v,p: 59% 18% 15%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] Weighted P-Frames: Y:27.9% UV:16.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] ref P L0: 67.4% 15.9% 12.2%  3.9%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] ref B L0: 92.0%  7.4%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] ref B L1: 99.2%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x1ff9360] kb/s:4178.51
```

I know there is a warning message during the conversion, but I still get valid mp4 out so I don't know if it is an issue or not.
I have tried using transpose=1 but it doesn't affect the output at all:
avconv -i input.mov -vf transpose=1 out.mp4

Answer (score 0):

I experimented a bit and finally found a combination that worked:

```
avconv -i input.mov -vf "transpose=1" -codec:v libx264 -strict experimental out.mp4
```

I think it was that I had -strict -2 instead of -strict experimental, though from the documentation I can't tell what 2 maps to or why that would cause it to ignore transpose. I've tried specifying the codec before and it did not work, but maybe it was the specific combination or arguments I was using before with the codec specification that caused it to be ignored.